# GitHub Copilot Extension Chat function not appearing in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I installed the Copilot extension, verified I was signed into my GitHub account, confirmed my billing/trial information, but I do not see the icon for the extension in my side panel to be able to engage the chat function. Does anything else need to be adjusted? This is happening on two different laptops.

[image: Screenshot of side panel missing Copilot]

I tried uninstalling and installing different versions of Copilot.

Comment: The side bar is part of a different extension called [Copilot Labs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot-labs)

Comment: The chat icon also shows up in the activity (side) bar. I'm having the same issue. Anyone that stumbles on this post can following the GitHub issue I opened: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues/4

Comment: Open "Output: Show Output Channels..." from the VS Code Command Palette and check if "GitHub Copilot Chat" is there and if "copilot token chat_enabled" is set to true: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues/436

Comment: Maybe organization policy is incorrect and you have a silent failure? For details, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues/551

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I followed the Beta invite email steps and its working correctly.

[image: Working copilot chat]

[image: Working copilot on Mac M2]

1. Download and install Visual Studio Code - Insiders (Green instead of blue icon on 15 May 2023)
   VS Code 1.79.0-insider and GitHub Copilot NIghtly v1.86.92

Already on the Insiders build? Make sure you are on the latest version!

2. In VS Code Insiders, go to the Extensions tab (Cmd+Shift+X) in the activity panel and search for and install the GitHub Copilot Nightly extension.
   If you have not previously authorized VS Code Insiders in your GitHub account, follow the steps to do so, you will be prompted to sign in.
3. A new Chat icon appears in the activity panel. Click on it to see the conversation interface.
   If that doesn't work, restart the editor and authorize GitHub Copilot to see the chat window.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. On macos here and there is no icon. I don't see any way to differentiate between insider or normal version of vscode, but I downloaded from https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders and the download doesn't actually say anything in particular that would hint to insiders build, I don't find any other link though.

Comment: I was not using the latest version of VS Code insiders. Updating it, resolved the issue.

Comment: @DrSocket on a mac, u try the top left Menu text "code xxx" and about will show the version number.

Answer (score 17):

You will have to enable `Copilot Chat in the IDE`

If personal Copilot:

- https://github.com/settings/copilot

If your Copilot is managed via your org:

```
https://github.com/organizations/<your org>/settings/copilot/policies
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my issue. If you are part of an org, Copilot Chat must be explicitly enabled in your org. If not, Copilot appears to load at startup but the extension icon disappears after a few seconds with no warning.